# ODBC error state S1092: postgresql through ODBC

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql, odbc

While performing an upgrade, our in-house software started to report the following strange error. It is a C++ application talking to a remote PostgreSQL database, defined through ODBC:

```
ODBC error state S1092, native error 0. 
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid attribute/option identifier
```

Both the client and the server are Centos 5.4 Xen guests with the following RPMs installed:

```
postgresql-libs-8.1.18-2.el5_4.1
postgresql-odbc-08.01.0200-3.1
postgresql-8.1.18-2.el5_4.1
postgresql-server-8.1.18-2.el5_4.1
```

Its possible the schema changed as part of the upgrade, could this explain the error message? What does this error message actually indicate, and do you know any likely causes of it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is something wrong not with PostgrSQL ODBC, but with unixODBC driver manager. Enable tracing of ODBC functions and see what causes this error.

To enable tracing you must edit your `odbcinst.ini` and do something like:

```
[ODBC]
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/tmp/odbc_log.txt
```